# In Cocoa/Obj-C, how to capture a cmd-c event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, keyboard-shortcuts, nstableview

I have an NSTableView that displays a few rows and columns.  The user is able to select multiple rows, and I'd like to be able to capture the cmd-c (copy) shortcut and do something custom (write the selected rows' info onto the clipboard).

So the question is how to set up a method so that it gets called when cmd-c is pressed in the context of the NSTableView being in focus right after selecting some rows with the mouse and keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is sent up the responder chain and caught in the copy:(id) method of for example an NSDOCUMENT if you have a NSDOCUMENT subclass. If your NSTABLEVIEW subclass acceptsFirstResponder a copy:(id) method should be enough.

Alternatively you can capture the key press in for example sendEvent:(NSEvent*)event

Comment: Thanks, it works.  I was overriding performKeyEquivalent: and checking the event's modifierFlags and characters but simply overriding acceptsFirstResponder: and copy: is cleaner.